# Precomp is disappearing and Mocha tracking points aren’t pasted

Tags: after-effects

Very newbie with Boris Mocha.
I want to use Mocha to replace a computer mouse cursor by an object. Here, with screenshots, it’s how I try to proceed.[image]

I then created a solid layer

[image]

Next, I pre-composed that layer

[image]

Following this tutorial :

, I applied my Mocha tracking data to my newly created comp (Red Solid 1 Comp 1)

[image]

But Sadly, It doesn’t work :

- My “Red Solid 1 Comp 1” has disappeared
- And the tracking hasn’t been pasted properly, I cannot see the
  tracking points within the “Red Solid 1 Comp 1”

[image]

What happened ? Please help!

PS: I use the latest version of AE and Boris Mocha to date, on my MBP Apple M1